# Current directory of process changes when initiated as a service

Tags: linux, services, node.js

I've written this service unit to run with **systemd**:

```
[Unit]
Description=NodeJS, Express server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/sm/test.js
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The test.js is equivalent to an `ls`, this is written:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readdir('.', (e,d)=> e ?console.log(e): console.log(d))
```

Running `node test.js` or even `sudo node test.js` or `node  /<pathTo>/test.js` from CLI outputs the directory where the script is running.

If this is initiated with **systemctl**, it logs the root directory.

What is the logic behind it? Why does the log change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because systemd does not have a default working directory. And therefor it uses `/` as such. Use `WorkingDirectory=` in your `[Service]` section to set the working directory.

Comment: Smart, thanks dude. But then node would be reading that variable?

Comment: This got nothing to do with node or any other program. This isn't a variable either. Not in the way you think it is, at least. Read up on the concept of a working directory [here](https://linuxize.com/post/current-working-directory/) or [here](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0020.php) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

Comment: But to summerize it a bit: Every program is executed somewhere a specific folder that is the "here". But this folder is not the folder the program is in, but the folder where it is executed from. If you are in /home/Minksy and execute mkdir (which is in /bin/mkdir) then you create a folder in your home, not in /bin/.

Comment: Yes, I got that from the links, now I know there are internal ways to set that in Node using `__dirname`, apart from switching cwd from the service unit file. Thanks.